# how to install a pack to a Windows portable executable/

Tags: software-installation, wine, pdf

I download a portable version of pdfxchange viewer from http://www.tracker-software.com/downloads/PDFX_Vwr_Port.zip. 
After unzip, I can run

```
PDFXCview.exe
```

directly, after adding its path to $PATH.
Note that this is a portable version, so it doesn't need installation. Although pdfxchange viewer also has installation version, the installed pdfxchange viewer will not encounter error while editing a pdf file, so I choose the portable version.

To add OCR feature to it, I download a language file from http://www.tracker-software.com/OCRBaseLangPack.zip.
After unzip, I get `OCRBaseLangPack.exe`, and I try to run it, but I get an error saying "pdf viewer and editior was not installed. Installation aborted". 
Does it mean that `OCRBaseLangPack.exe` can't find `PDFXCview.exe`?
Is it because my pdfxchange viewer is portable, and doesn't need to install, so `OCRBaseLangPack.exe` can't find `PDFXCview.exe`?

How can I install `OCRBaseLangPack.exe` to `PDFXCview.exe` then?

Thanks!

Comment: WHere doet that link discuss  portable windows software/

Comment: It's the same thing: install Wine, and open your executable with it.